# is there a way to delete older version of android app through an updated app version

Tags: android

Please allow me to explain the problem, I built and released and android app that uses google map. The certificate used to sign that app was lost and so I couldn't release the next update under the same name as the previous per google play rules.

For this reason I was forced to sign the app with a new certificate and rename the app. Now user with previous are reporting issues with double instances of the same. indeed not much of difference in those two instances except the names and certificates used to sign them.

So my question is, how can ease the transition work for my users, I know uninstalling the old version and installing the new does the trick, but I am just wondering if there is some level of control that I can implement either through code of settings in google play to make things clearer and easier for the app users? 
Also if you think my perspective of the problem is wrong too, please suggest a better one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would personally be a bit upset if any random application could uninstall any other random application. (And, without certificates to prove the correlation, these apps might as well be random.) If it were me, I'd just ask users to delete the old one manually.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a security issue, and something that the Android libraries wouldn't allow.

Comment: I clearly understand the security issues that could arise if these are done code wise, but I more hoping for a way to do that through settings in the Google play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question: [Implicit intent to uninstall application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868460/implicit-intent-to-uninstall-application)

Will show you how you can use and fire an intent that will start the uninstall process for the user.

You can use the PackageManager to find out if the old version is present. If It is create and launch an uninstall intent. Perhaps tell the users that you are going to do that with a dialog or something before launching the intent.

Comment: I think I will try the suggested method here. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can detect if your old app is installed and prevent the user from using your new one until it's uninstalled. Ex. using an "if" statement on your main activity that creates an alert dialog if it detects that your old package is installed and directs user to uninstall it before continuing. Just a thought!

[Android - check for presence of another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694267/android-check-for-presence-of-another-app)