# Android Background service actived on any app installed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-permissions

i am new to android and i want to ask a question about android background services.

i have created a background service and which is activated after every one minute and pop up some message.

i want this service to activate to user whenever user installed another application to phone.
is there any method to check this.

is there any method that check whenever any app is run for the first time and request user for permission?? OR what permission it requires from user??

Waiting for answer.
Thanks in advance for good replies.

Comment: A very similar question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394141/android-detect-when-app-is-installed

Answer (score 0):

Set up a BroadcastReceiver for the android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent.

Comment: is there any method that check whenever any other app request user for permission.??

Comment: Not that I can see.  Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and see if you see anything likely.

Answer (score 0):

Using Broadcast receiver you can do so as shown below:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(arg0, "A New Package has been Installed!!!").show();

    }

}
```

You should register this broadcast receiver in your manifest as shown below:

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

From the above code a toast will be displayed whenever a new package is displayed. Hope this helps as it had worked for me.

Comment: is there any method that check whenever any app is run for the first time and request user for permission?? OR what permission it requires from user??