# How to Automatically Install App in device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

It's Possible? I have two app in play store and app store when i have install one app second app install automatically.
How i can achieve this in xamarin form ?

Comment: Only system app has the permission to install app automatically.

Comment: I believe that if system app can install another app automatically then we can also.

Comment: @ChetanRawat system app is just like administrator and developers is not.you can use deeplink inside your first app and when user open it up,they must install the second application to continue ( better a dialog for user to understand)

Comment: Possibly you can do is check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394141/android-detect-when-app-is-installed and then in broadcast reciver start install another app

Comment: Check the official document here https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist