# accessing sharedpreference across applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `getDefaultSharedPreferences(con)` in my application to store preferences. Now I want to access this shared preference in another application.
I used following method:

```
con = this.createPackageContext("com.example.preferences", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences filePref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
            if(filePref != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file pref not null --- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file pref is null **** ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Map<String,?> allkeys = filePref.getAll();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file pref size **** "+allkeys.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : allkeys.entrySet()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "~~~ file pref --- map values --- "+entry.getKey() + ": "+entry.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Another way which tried is specifying file name & accessing it, as follow;

```
SharedPreferences filePref = gvcon.getSharedPreferences("com.example.preferences_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

With this method I am able to access `SharedPrefernce` file, it returns file is not null but when I check for file size it shows 0. I am not able to read preference value from file.
I used `shareduserid` of another application so that I get full access to that application.
What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: take a look at this reply

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13236870/1936366

and this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your problem completely, but some times this implementation will help you to access data across packages. 
Use `getSharedPreferences()` to store data in shared preferences

This method will store data in shared preferences

```
public void dataWriter(){
    String strShareValue = "Hello! this is shared data";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
    editor.commit();
}
```

You can access that shared data from another package using this code sample

```
public void dataRead(){
 Context con;
     try {
         con = createPackageContext("PACKAGE NAME THAT SHARES DATA", 0);
         SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences("demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         String dataShared = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
      }
     catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
         Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My concern is when sharedpreferences are created without specifying name but using default method, ie using prefernceactivity & are stored under /data/data/packagename_preference.xml  In this case i am not able to read preference value from xml file.