# Android - shared variable between apps

Tags: android

I'm building a shared library that can be shared in many applications

I need global variable that all apps using this library can  write and read the variable.

I check the solutions:

1) shard preference -  irrelevant, because I do not have a standalone application.

2) content Provider-  irrelevant, because I do not have a standalone application.

3) SQLite DB -  irrelevant, because I do not have a standalone application.

4) file in SD card -  problem if there is no SD card.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications Possible dupplicite question

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful, if you'd provide a little  bit more context. What kind of data do you need to share across application boundaries? What exactly makes those solutions listed "irrelevant"?

Comment: I need flag (Boolean variable) to share across application boundaries,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally am not 100% sure if you can or cannot use sharedPreferences between two applications, however here is a post I found that guides you on how to do it: http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/

Here is another post that may help you: [SharedPreferences between arbitrary applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196182/sharedpreferences-between-arbitrary-applications)

Comment: Thank you very much!!
To use a shared preference of another application I need to know the package name  
 context.createPackageContext(package name);
 but I don't know, I cannot be sure that one of the apps (with specific package name) that use  shared library is installed on the phone.

Comment: Also starting from Android 7 (API 24) you aren't able to access SharedPreferences of another app.