# Check android device possible to install?

Tags: android, installation

I have a question about installation of an app on android device. I have an application that requires that a user installs another application. That required app may be different at different times, but sometimes user device cannot install this required app for some reason. I want to check programmatically that a user can or cannot install a required app. Is it possible??

Comment: please write things understandable

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically

Comment: i sorry about my english. i tried your link but i want to let user install app from google play, some time they cannot install it so i want to detect user can or cannot install it, not installed or not yet installed. ane thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can check whether another application *is already* installed, but there's no simply way to determine whether another application *is technically capable* of being installed.

This determination is based on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the other application (at least), and possibly some internal checks that occur within other application's code. You would need to know the requirements for the other application (minimum SDK version, supported screen sizes, camera and other hardware requirements, etc.) and check for them yourself.