# Opening Different Android Map Applications

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm working on an Android app which allows users to save and categorise locations. The user can navigate to a location from inside the app via an intent. Currently, the Intent opens the location in Google Navigation.

I've been asked to add support for navigation with Sygic.

The trouble I've hit is that the Uri's for Sygic and Google Navigation are different:

Google Navigation: `google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude`

Sygic: `com.sygic.aura://coordinate|latitude|longitude`

I'm struggling to understand how the user can choose between the two different apps when the Intent is chosen from within my app.

I've looked at using `createChooser`, but that only accepts one Uri.

Can somebody give me a pointer in the right direction, please?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, though I don't see how that helps... The examples they provide show using one Uri across multiple apps. I need to use a specific Uri for a specific app.

Comment: you can try to check if the Sygic app is already installed on a client's device and show a chooser on your own. here you can find how to check if an app is installed or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically