# Android - Using try and catch

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my try to start an intent that uses an another application. But if that application is not installed on that phone i want to show a dialog to inform the user to install the app. I tried the code below:

```
try {
    startActivity(i);
} catch (Exception e) {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    b.setMessage("Message Here");
    b.create().show();
}
```

`

Comment: _"I tried the code below"_ And...? What happened? In what way did the behavior you got deviate from the behavior you were expecting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically

Comment: @Michael and the catch statement was useless

Comment: Micheal can you help me in this using try and catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check installed apps by using this methond

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    boolean result;
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        result = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: actually that intent  opens a video player (like mx player and vlc player)........... so there can be many

Comment: Then you can check all available PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);