# callback google play on installed app

Tags: java, android, callback

We are creating an app where you can share an app, which sends the user to the google play store to download another app.
My question is, how can I know if some user actually downloaded and installed that app?
Is there a some sort of callback you get from the play store?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling startActivityForResult() with the Play Store intent. Then, override the onActivityResult() method in your Activity and check if the app is installed. This might help: [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
isAppInstalledBefore("com.example.anappblabla");

private boolean isAppInstalledBefore(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
       pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
       installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       installed = false;
    }
    return installed; //returns boolean
}
```

Comment: note: This returns result of app which installed on device on that current time. But it could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**No, but:**

What I would do is trying to get the package name (generally in the URL for example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**dev.laurentmeyer.contactautocompleteview** of the target app (which is unique): something like `dev.laurentmeyer.whateverApp` (it's the one I'm personally using). Then scan the installed apps with [this Helper](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) and you'll be sure if it has been installed or not.