# Android check installed app failed

Tags: android, opencv

In my program there is check if `OpenCV Manager` app installed. I got idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/4762282), here is my code:

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context cnt, String packName) {
    PackageManager pm = cnt.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is calling from:

```
private boolean isOpenCVInstalled() {
    return GlobalFunctions.isAppInstalled(this, "org.opencv.engine");
}
```

On my phone and tablet it works fine. But on `Samsung Galaxy Xcover 3` phone it is always returns `true`, so in form with OpenCV camera preview I get `package not found, install?` message and `file not found` on accept installation.

What is wrong with galaxy phone? Or with my code?

**UPDATE**

[This link](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4162) makes me sad. Does that mean there is no solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe [this link](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4162).

Now with my solution it is not important. I changed OpenCV initialization by `initAsync` to `initDebug` in static section of Activity class. I have OpenCV library projects linked to my project, so it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me:

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(Context ctx,String packageName) {
            PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            for (ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
                if (app.packageName.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: It is opposite situation - it is always `false`.