# Open Facebook Page in Facebook App (if installed) on Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I would like to open my Facebook page from my Android app, if the Facebook app is available - if not: this page should be open in the default browser.

for this i tried the following code:

```
try {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/MY_PAGE_ID"));
startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_NAME")));
}
```

Problem is:
I have here an Android device with the newest version of Facebook.
If I would like to open from my app the Facebook page, the Facebook app will open , but without my page.

I only see the message:

> Trouble Loading Timeline.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`"fb://page/` does not work with newer versions of the FB app. You should use `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=` for newer versions.

This is a full fledged working code currently live in one of my apps:

```
public static String FACEBOOK_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/YourPageName";
public static String FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID = "YourPageName";

//method to get the right URL to use in the intent
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
            if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions of fb app
                return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
            } else { //older versions of fb app
                return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
        }
    }
```

This method will return the correct url for app if installed or web url if app is not installed.

Then start an intent as follows:

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(this);
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

That's all you need.

Comment: source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/1048340

Comment: That worked like charm

Comment: Works *almost* all the time.  This crashes if the user has the Facebook app installed, but disabled.

Comment: Gud catch... Catch the specific exception... Also feel free to add it to the answer...

Comment: what if i have only the facebok id rather than the [pagename]

Comment: basically you just need to open the page and use the string that follows `https://www.facebook.com/`. This is generally the page name. If page name is not set explicitly then use the string that appears after the facebook domain `https://www.facebook.com/<whatever is here>`

Comment: i used this and it works but there is no like button for my page, also contents are a bit different..

Comment: @Arthas thats strange. Can you share a screenshot showing the differences?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic when i open my page with your method it shows about , videos , photos and posts , However the other options like like etc are missing. I'll add screenshots

Comment: @AndroidMechanic http://imgur.com/a/U1Qeu You can check here : D

Comment: Happening in my app too. was working fine earlier. Looks like a change in fb app. I'll try checking if there is a workaround and will update the answer if i find something.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic cool , dont you think we should have an offical documented mechanism to open link in social apps?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-this-hack-to-open-a-specific-facebook-page-from-your-android-app/ found this and its working check it out !

Comment: until now Feb 20th, 2017:
*"fb://profile/MY_PAGE_ID"* : not working ; 
*"fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL* : go to the page but not home page (without LIKE or Contact Us ... button). ; 
*"fb://page/PAGE_ID"* : WORKING FINE !

Comment: `fb://page/` still works on the newer version. My facebook app is up to date, and it still opens my page correctly.

Comment: Today facebook does not allow unauthorized graph queries for pages. I managed to get the id of a facebook page by opening the page in an incognito tab, the first xhr request holds the page id in the query parameter.

Comment: ApplicationInfo.versionCode seems to be no longer accessible

Comment: Please help to open Messenger by facebook user id?

Comment: ApplicationInfo.versionCode is now deprecated in API Level 29.

Also this crashes if the user installed the facebook app but didn't login.

Comment: I'm trying to open a specific post on a Facebook page, which works fine on iOS with `fb://profile/123/posts?id=456`. On Android, the `fb://page/123`still works for me, but there is no way to pass a parameter for the expected post. It's possible to do this by using fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" and passing the URL as  "https://www.facebook.com/123/posts/456". Is it possible to do this through `fb://page`?

Answer (score 17):

This works on the latest version:

Go to https://graph.facebook.com/ (https://graph.facebook.com/fsintents for instance).

Copy your id
Use this method:

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/<id_here>"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<user_name_here>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for my need. The "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" answer above for newer versions takes users to a page of posts by the entity, not really their "page". Did not research this further. Also, very important that you use the ID of the page NOT the vanity page name!!

Comment: Agree. This opens the actual page, not a search after the page. For those having trouble getting the page id, get it from here: http://findmyfbid.com/

Comment: not opening the facebook app. Always open the browser even facebook app is installed

Answer (score 12):

Okay I modifed @AndroidMechanics Code, because on devices were facebook is disabled the app crashes!

here is the modifed getFacebookUrl:

```
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;

            boolean activated =  packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).enabled;
            if(activated){
                if ((versionCode >= 3002850)) { 
                    return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
                } else { 
                    return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
                }
            }else{
                return FACEBOOK_URL;
            }
         } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return FACEBOOK_URL; 
        }
    }
```

The only added thing is to look if the app is disabled or not if it is disabled the app will call the webbrowser!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that mixes the code by [Jared Rummler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/6322400) and [AndroidMechanic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564284/6322400).

*Note:* `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=` redirects to a weird facebook page that doesn't have the like and other important buttons, which is why I try `fb://page/`. It works fine with the current Facebook version (126.0.0.21.77, June 1st 2017). The catch might be useless, I left it just in case.

```
public static String getFacebookPageURL(Context context)
{
    final String FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID = "123456789";
    final String FACEBOOK_URL = "MyFacebookPage";

    if(appInstalledOrNot(context, "com.facebook.katana"))
    {
        try
        {
            return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
            // previous version, maybe relevant for old android APIs ?
            // return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    else
    {
        return FACEBOOK_URL;
    }

}
```

Here's the `appInstalledOrNot` function which I took (and modified) from Aerrow's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/6322400)

```
private static boolean appInstalledOrNot(Context context, String uri)
{
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    }
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
    }

    return false;
}
```

How to get the Facebook ID of a page:

1. Go to your page
2. Right-click and `View Page Source`
3. Find in page: `fb://page/?id=`
4. Here you go!

Comment: that try catch in 'getFacebookPageURL' has no function

Comment: You're right, I edited it as a comment for reference.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. "fb://page/{your_page_id}" work fine with me. Facebook version 196.0.0.41.95 (Nov 07 2018)

Answer (score 2):

**you can use this:**

```
try {
                Intent followIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" +
                        "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/"+scoped user id+"/"));
                activity.startActivity(followIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" + user name)));
                String errorMessage = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Message is empty" : e.getMessage();
            }
```

*attention:*
you can get scoped user id from "**link**" permission facebook api

Answer (score -3):

**I already have answered here and it's working for me, please refer this 
link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40133225/3636561**

```
    String socailLink="https://www.facebook.com/kfc";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String facebookUrl = Utils.getFacebookUrl(getActivity(), socailLink);
    if (facebookUrl == null || facebookUrl.length() == 0) {
        Log.d("facebook Url", " is coming as " + facebookUrl);
        return;
    }
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
```

please refer link to get rest part.