# Android open facebook page link in facebook app if installed ,

Tags: android, facebook

how to open Facebook page link in Facebook App if installed , and if the app is not installed open in default browser in android ??

i tried this code but its not working ??

```
     Face.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = null;
            String Facebook = dbList.get(0).getFacebook().toString();
            try {
                // get the Twitter app if possible
                getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.android", 0);
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" +Facebook));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no Twitter app, revert to browser
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/?hl=en"));
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using this code you can open user profile

```
public static void opneFacebookProfile(Activity activity, String id) {
        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(activity, id);
        facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
        activity.startActivity(facebookIntent);
    }
```

Comment: what is `getFacebookPageURL`?

Comment: check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564211/open-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-if-installed-on-android

Answer (score 1):

### check this link here

here more answer and this help you

click here
  [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I work with Unity Android games. The task is to open a Facebook Fan page in the FB app if it is installed. All I need to do is:

1. Create Android Library and check if FB installed:

   ```
    public boolean isFbInstalled(Activity a) {
    PackageManager packageManager = a.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana",                  0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions of fb app, no need to handle older
            return true;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
   ```

   }
2. Go to [this service](https://www.piliapp.com/facebook/smart-url/) and use generated links for different platforms :)