# Android: How to check if my other apps are installed on a device

Tags: android, file

I have several Android apps in play store and when a user installs one of my apps, how can that app find out that my other apps are installed on this device or not?

I wish to search using : `com.developer.*`  pattern.
Can we make such check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)

Comment: Just edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function to find the application using the package name of the application you want.

```
 private boolean appAvailable(String package_name) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(package_name, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            installed = false;
        }
        return installed;
    }
```

Or you can use below function also

```
public static boolean isAppAvailable(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> boolean findFaceebook = isAppAvailable(context,
>   "com.Facebook.katana");

Comment: @SHA2NK: If helpful Up Vote and Accept the answer.

Comment: That's really cool @rakshit .
But I have one more question, can we do * search like:
package name:  com.developer.*     ?