# Check whether install is first install or user have installed app previously

Tags: android, installation, package-info

What I want to achieve is get to know whether app is installed first time or user have installed this app previously in android.

Comment: i would say that you better use an API interaction here.

Api should be like this :
As the user opens your app the API should send the user's **deviceId** (IMEI or any Unique number) to your API and you store it in your DB.
Now even if the user deletes the app, you will be having the details of his/her deviceId. 
So, in case of reinstallation of app, fetch the deviceId again and check if the deviceId is already there in your DB or not. If available, it's a reinstall else first install..

That's it.. simple and elegant :)

Comment: @Piyush this is asked specifically for ANDROID OS not for iOS.

Comment: @VaibhavKadam Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android

Comment: Do you want to know if the user is running the app second time after the installation or you want to check even for a fresh install ?

Comment: @Piyush that won't determine whether my app is installed 1st time. If user uninstall and reinstall then app can not determine whether the install is for 1st time.

Comment: @Nishith yeah its about install and reinstall.

Comment: @VaibhavKadam In this scenario sohaib's approach would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. If the user uses an email to register/login to your app you could store information regarding if the email was used before or not.