# how to share a image using instagram in background without opening app share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, instagram

I am developing an app that has a functionality for sharing a image in facebook and instagram.once user clicked share button for both facebook and instagram it first check whether app is installed on our device as well check whether user login on the app.once the checking is completed the image hase to be posted on those app without opening facebook and instagram app.can anyone tell me the code for doing such functionality.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android

Comment: package name istagram: com.instagram.android

Comment: facebook: com.facebook.katana

Comment: thanks for your answer,but what i want to know is there any way to share images in facebook and instagram without opening the native app.the image hase to be posted in background.once the sharing is done just displaying a toast of success message.