# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent on another application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm trying to open another application's(1mg) activity from my application. I've found class name and package name of another application(1mg) from its manifest file by decompiling the apk. What am I doing wrong? Also, if you can also help me to check if the app(1mg) is installed or not and if not installed the it should open www.1mg.com

**Gradle**

```
11-13 02:00:22.590 13163-13163/com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor, PID: 13163
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.aranoah.healthkart.plus/.others.AboutUsActivity } from ProcessRecord{894ac0c 13163:com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor/u0a182} (pid=13163, uid=10182) not exported from uid 10102
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3115)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4241)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4580)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4548)
        at com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.NavigationActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationActivity.java:122)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:154)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5657)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22453)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

**NavigationActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Trending Topics");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor("#00ACC1"));
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,SleepDisorderActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
//        return true;
//    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
//        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
//        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//
//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }
//
//        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
//    }

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        startActivity(new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,SymptomActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        if (intent != null) {
            intent.setClassName("com.aranoah.healthkart.plus","com.aranoah.healthkart.plus.others.AboutUsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)

Comment: No. Please read the info clearly. My main task is to solve the gradle error.

Comment: You are not getting a "gradle error", you are getting a RuntimeException. "Also, if you can also help me to check if the app(1mg) is installed or not and if not installed the it should open www.1mg.com" seems to me like you are asking that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.aranoah.healthkart.plus","com.aranoah.healthkart.plus.pharmacy.search.autocomplete.SearchActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Also, it requires you to add the correct class name. It all depends on how much you go through the manifest file of another app and perform the hit and trial method and hope that it might work out soon.