# How to show a specific app's icon from the installed apps on android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, appicon

I want to show a specific app's icon from my installed apps, not every apps icon.
First I want to check if that package is installed or not, to do that I got help from the answers of this question-
[How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)
Then if that package is installed, I want to show that package's app icon in my application and want to launch it by tapping on it.
Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which parts are you having issues with? Did you come across the `PackageManager#getApplicationIcon()` and `PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage()` methods in your research? Are you having trouble linking those to a `Button`, or `ImageButton`, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from PackageManager.

```
Drawable appIcon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("apps.package.name");
```

check the below link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

You can add a click event with intent to start the new app.