# How to check what the user clicked on uninstall dialog box created using intent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog, uninstallation

i am trying create an app that is capable of uninstalling the other installed apps . So when i am using uninstall intent the dialog box opened ask for Ok or cancel. so how can i get informed whether the user selected ok or cancel as i need to hide the the uninstall button that is pressed. Assigned as button present in public class viewholder at end of the code

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>  {
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
private Context mContext;
List<Drawable> images;
List<String> titles;
List<String> apps;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public void uninstallAPK(String apkPackageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + apkPackageName));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}

private void goToUrl (String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    launchBrowser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    launchBrowser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
    mContext.startActivity(launchBrowser);
    mainActivity.finish();
}


public Adapter(Context ctx, List<String> titles, List<Drawable> 
images,List<String> apps){
    this.titles =titles;
    this.images = images;
    this.apps = apps;
    this.inflater =LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    mContext = ctx;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int 
position) {
    holder.title.setText(titles.get(position));
    holder.gridIcon.setImageDrawable(images.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView gridIcon;
    TextView title;
    Button button;
    Button button3;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        gridIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uninstallAPK(apps.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                //want to hide the button if ok is pressed otherwise want 
                to show the button
            }


        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ParseQuery<ParseObject> linkwa = new 
                ParseQuery<ParseObject>("package");
                linkwa.whereEqualTo("packid", 
                apps.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                linkwa.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, 
                    ParseException e) {
                        if(e==null && objects.size()>0){
                            for (ParseObject object:objects){
                                goToUrl(object.getString("link"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Dynamically register a broadcast receiver for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_package_removed) and watch for a broadcast matching the app that you asked to uninstall, to find out if the user uninstalls it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually workaround that you can give a try

1. StartActivityFotResult which will ensure you will get the callback inside onActivityResult

   ```
   public void uninstallAPK(String apkPackageName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + apkPackageName));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);

    }
   ```
2. Now you can check the Result-Code whether it is a success or not `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELLED`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1234) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //Deleted
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Dismissed
        }
    }
   }//onActivityResult
   ```

2.1. If the above-mentioned solution did not work then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1234) {
        if (appInstalledOrNot("required_app_package_name")){
           // Dismissed
        }else { 
           //Deleted
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult


private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

PS. Checking if an app is installed or not is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/8342718)

Comment: I am getting rename reference for startActivityForResult as i am using these functions in adapter class not in second or main activity.
so can you please help

Comment: You can use callback then, register callback inside an adapter then when it is pressed invoke function inside an activity, this will help you

Comment: @TusharJain If you find my answer is helpful then please consider voting for it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't really know how is your implementation, but ideally I would have two button. One for cancel another for uninstall. And I would have set clicklistener on both of the button. So, whenever, the onclickListener is executed, means user pressed the button of the dialog box. So, first thing, I would dissmiss the dialog, second thing based on the button user clicked

```
public void onClick(View v){
   if(v.getId == R.id.btn_dialog_uninstall){
      uninstallPackage("package_name");
      dialog.dissmiss();
   }else{
    dialog.dissmiss(); // user pressed cancelled;
 }
```

hope that helps.